# Best way to preview a template inside a div (without IFRAME)?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, themes, preview

I'm working on a CMS system where the user has the ability to select between a number of different templates for their site.  When they select from the list of templates on the left I want the middle of the page to show the preview of the template and the right side to show a property inspector for manipulating things like colors, font sizes, sections, etc.  Clicking on an element inside the preview changes what is focused and thus changes the property inspector.

The big challenge is that the templates are designed by 3rd party designers and the CSS is designed with the expectation that there is no other CSS (like the CSS for the CMS).  I might force them to restrict everything their design to work on any page and to always have a top level DIV that I can just inject into the page.

I could IFRAME it but that is not ideal because DOM manipulation becomes more complicated.

Ultimately I have full control over the template structure and how they are made but I'd like to keep it as simple as possible for designers.

What's the best way to go about structuring this kind of setup?

Answer (score 1):

Given the requirements of no iframe (which would be the right way), I see 2 solutions:

1. Put the template in a div with a certain class/id and preprocess the CSS to prefix every selector with that class.
2. Use the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM), but then you would [only target Chrome](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom).

Comment: That might work.  Shadow DOM seems like it would have a bit more overhead as well.  With it inside a DIV they'd have to not apply any CSS on the BODY or the main wrapping DIV.  I would have to have some default and force them to use it.  Probably no margins, padding on both.